# How can I update the pattern in masked input field in Drupal?

Tags: input, drupal-7, maskedinput, bulkupdate

I am having the masked input field for **US phone number** in this pattern  **(999) 999-9999** and saved all data in this pattern now I am changing the pattern to **999.999.999**
 but when I change the pattern it's not getting updated in the filed.

I added this field to user accounts now if I want to update the masked input field I need to manually update all user in form save.

and only in  **form save its working** not in programmatic `user_save()`

I used bulk update user doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not getting updated"? If you expect your existing content to be "converted" automagicaly to the new pattern I would say it is normal that it does not..

Comment: Solved: updated my field  value using query solved my problem. Because masked input changes the value only when the form is rendered and replaces the pattern using jquery.